# Import org.apache.net.* in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm trying to upload some files to my FTP server using Kotlin.

I compile my programs on the command line as:
`kotlinc main.kt -include-runtime -d main.jar`

And when I import `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` I got an error as:

`main.kt:7:12: error: unresolved reference: apache`.

I've downloaded `commons-net-3.6.jar` but I have no ideas on how to include this file to my actual project.

How can I do to successfully import `org.apache.*` libraries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very strong advice: *don't* try to manage jar files for Kotlin (or any other JVM language) manually. `commons-net` happens not to have any other dependencies, but it's very much an exception.

Instead use a build system such as Gradle. Assuming you use IDEA, follow [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-gradle.html) to create a new project, just check Kotlin/JVM in step 2.

Then if you go to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net/3.6, the Gradle tab gives you the line you need to add to `build.gradle` file:

```
compile group: 'commons-net', name: 'commons-net', version: '3.6'
```

EDIT: to work with Gradle from command line without IDEA or Eclipse, see https://guides.gradle.org/creating-new-gradle-builds/#initialize_a_project. Try if

```
gradle init --type kotlin-application
```

works, according to https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/6489 it should. If not, start with

```
gradle init --type java-application
```

and follow https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html and the examples linked there for the Kotlin specifics.

Comment: Thanks but I'm on a backup computer and it doesn't have enough power to run a software like IDEA. Is there a way to create a FTP client using Gradle if needed but without IDEA?

Comment: Yes, I added the relevant links.

Answer (score 1):

Are you avoiding using Maven or Gradle? I recommend using one of those. Here is a Maven example.

You can build and run the program with these commands once the files are made.

```sh
mvn package
java -jar target/ftp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>ftp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html -->
    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.41</kotlin.version>
        <main.class>com.demo.ftp.ApplicationKt</main.class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals> <goal>test-compile</goal> </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>single</goal> </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**src/main/kotlin/com/demo/ftp/Application.kt**

```
package com.demo.ftp

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

fun main() {
    println("Hello Kotlin!")
    val client = FTPClient()
}
```

Comment: I'm going to use Gradle because `pom.xml` scared me. I found how to use Gradle using command line [here](https://www.codexpedia.com/kotlin/build-and-run-kotlin-from-command-line-using-gradle/). Thanks.